Filament bulk action sum only selected rows
im trying to get the select event of bulk action to get row details
    public function table(Table $table): Table
    {
        return $table
                ->query(Order::query()->whereNotNull(['captured_at'])->latest())
                ->columns([
                        TextColumn::make('id')->searchable(),
                        TextColumn::make('identifier')->searchable(),
                        TextColumn::make('driver.name')->searchable(),
                        TextColumn::make('total_price')->summarize(Sum::make())->money('IQD')->searchable(),
                        TextColumn::make('captured_amount')->summarize(Sum::make())->money('IQD')->searchable(),
                        TextColumn::make('wallets_amount')->summarize(Sum::make())->money('IQD')->searchable(),
                        TextColumn::make('captured_status')->badge()->searchable(),
                        TextColumn::make('captured_at')->date()->searchable(),
                    ])
                ->bulkActions([
                                       BulkAction::make('Create')
                            ->label(fn () => $this->tableFilters['driver_id']['value'] == null ? __('Select a driver') : __('Collect'))
                            ->icon(fn () => $this->tableFilters['driver_id']['value'] == null ? '' : 'heroicon-o-plus')
                            ->color(fn () => $this->tableFilters['driver_id']['value'] == null ? 'danger' : 'primary')
                            ->action(fn ($records) => $this->generateCollectionList($records,$this->tableFilters['driver_id']['value']))
                            ->requiresConfirmation()
                            ->disabled(fn () => $this->tableFilters['driver_id']['value'] == null)
                            ->modalHeading('Create Collection List ?')
                            ->modalDescription(fn($records) => new HtmlString("You're going to create a collection list for <strong style='color:lime'>{$records->count()}</strong> orders of <strong style='color:lime'> {$this->getDriverName($records)} </strong> ?"))
                            ->modalSubmitActionLabel('Yes, create it')
                            ->deselectRecordsAfterCompletion()
                            ->fetchSelectedRecords(fn ($record) => dd($record))


                ])
                ->striped()->defaultSort('created_at', 'desc');
    }


i want to change the Sum::make() value depending on selected rows ( sum only selected rows )

Hi there. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic for more information about asking good questions on StackOverflow.

Hmm,i guess some modification to the function below might work.
public function table(Table $table): Table

{

  return $table

    ->query(Order::query()->whereNotNull(['captured_at'])->latest())

    ->columns([

      TextColumn::make('id')->searchable(),

      TextColumn::make('identifier')->searchable(),

      TextColumn::make('driver.name')->searchable(),

      TextColumn::make('total_price')->summarize(Sum::make())->money('IQD')->searchable(),

      TextColumn::make('captured_amount')->summarize(Sum::make())->money('IQD')->searchable(),

      TextColumn::make('wallets_amount')->summarize(Sum::make())->money('IQD')->searchable(),

      TextColumn::make('captured_status')->badge()->searchable(),

      TextColumn::make('captured_at')->date()->searchable(),

    ])

    ->bulkActions([

      BulkAction::make('Create')

        ->label(fn () => $this->tableFilters['driver_id']['value'] == null ? __('Select a driver') : __('Collect'))

        ->icon(fn () => $this->tableFilters['driver_id']['value'] == null ? '' : 'heroicon-o-plus')

        ->color(fn () => $this->tableFilters['driver_id']['value'] == null ? 'danger' : 'primary')

        ->action(fn ($records) => $this->generateCollectionList($records, $this->tableFilters['driver_id']['value']))

        ->requiresConfirmation()

        ->disabled(fn () => $this->tableFilters['driver_id']['value'] == null)

        ->modalHeading('Create Collection List ?')

        ->modalDescription(fn($records) => new HtmlString("You're going to create a collection list for <strong style='color:lime'>{$records->count()}</strong> orders of <strong style='color:lime'> {$this->getDriverName($records)} </strong> ?"))

        ->modalSubmitActionLabel('Yes, create it')

        ->deselectRecordsAfterCompletion()

        ->fetchSelectedRecords(fn ($records) => $this->handleSelectedRecords($records))

    ])

    ->striped()->defaultSort('created_at', 'desc');

}



public function handleSelectedRecords($records)

{

  // Assuming $records is a collection of models

  foreach ($records as $record) {

    // Process each record as needed

    // For example, you can log details or manipulate data

    // Log::info($record->id);



    // Example: Accessing record details

    // echo $record->id; 

  }



  // Return any necessary data or perform further actions

  // For example, you might want to return something or perform additional logic

}


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
